# Is there a way to efficiently count column values in A falling within ranges in B using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have created some code to handle the following task:

```
ref = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
user    event
1441    120120102
1441    120120888
1443    120122122
1445    120124452
1445    120123525
1446    120123463", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
user    event1        event2
1440    120123432     120156756
1441    120128523     120156545
1441    120123333     120146444
1441    120122344     120122355", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What I have here is a function (credit to user Carlos Cinelli) that will allow me to go line by line on the table `data` and search and record how many events of ref are sandwiched between event1 and event2, by `user` id.

Now, I am wondering if there is a faster way to do the function below:

```
count <- function(x,y,z) ref[, sum(event >=x & event <= y & user ==z)]
data[, count:=mapply(x=event1, y=event2, z=user, count)]
```

I haven't been able to do much and was wondering if the `data.table` package would have anything that can help with making the above faster. Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to think in terms of rolling joins....

Comment: Arun, thanks for your response! Yes, the data is my mistake, it is an error to let event1>event2. The problem I ran into with foverlaps is that (I could be wrong) I couldn't seem to find a way to search for how many of `event` were sandwiched between `event1` and `event2` BASED on the `user` id. It seems that I couldn't figure out how and if I could only find the overlap joins by user id. Would I be correct or wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the examples from `?foverlaps`. They clearly show how you can join based on overlapping intervals within other identifiers.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3+
setDT(ref)
setDT(data)

setkey(ref[, event2 := event])
ans = foverlaps(data, ref, by.x=c("user", "event1", "event2"), which=TRUE, nomatch=0L)
```

Your example is particularly bad because there are *no overlaps*. So I can't really demonstrate the next few steps. But `ans` should provide you with overlapping row indices of `ref` (`yid`) for each row in `data` (`xid`). And the overlaps are obtained *within `user`* - since it was set as a key column as well.

I hope you can take it from here... If you find this doesn't resolve, please post an example that I can run to reproduce the same issue you're running into.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Non-equi joins were recently implemented and available in the [current development version of data.table, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). This can be performed in a quite straightforward manner using this feature:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(ref); setDT(data)
data[ref, .N, by=.EACHI, nomatch=0L, on=.(user, event1 <= event, event2 >= event)]
# returns an empty data.table here since no overlaps are found..
```